# How to send a complex object to a Razor page

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, razor-pages

I am working on an ASP.NET Core 6.0 Identity project. I want to pass an `ApplicationUser` object to the `LoginWith2fs.cshtml` page from the `Login.cshtml` page.

This is my code - login page:

```
return RedirectToPage("./LoginWith2fa", new 
                                        { 
                                            UserSent = user, 
                                            ReturnUrl = returnUrl, 
                                            RememberMe = Input.RememberMe 
                                        });
```

Code in `LoginWith2fa` page:

```
// Created this property in the LoginWith2fa page. Not sure this is needed or not
public ApplicationUser UserSent { get; set; }

public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(ApplicationUser UserSent, bool rememberMe, string returnUrl = null)
{
    // More code here
    // the  ApplicationUser object has null values in its properties such as username and email
    // However the rememberMe and returnUrl variables have correct values
}
```

Comment: Can you add the `ApplicationUser` class definition to the post, and does it have a constructor?

Comment: no reason to return/redirect from the login controller... just set the form to post to LoginWith2fa:   <form method="post" asp-page="./LoginWith2fa">

Comment: You are trying to pass the complex object to the another page in query string with the user information. It's not recommend and security. Directly passing the Email to the another page and use the usermanager to get the application user.